# How can I listen to INotifyCollectionChanged in a wpf user control

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifycollectionchanged

I have a user control. there I want to maintain a collection as a dependency property. Suppose that property is bound to a collection which implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

Now suppose the collection got added or removed with some item how can i listen to that change in the user control.

Answer (score 3):

You can't listen to it, since `CollectionChanged` is not a `RoutedEvent`.

WPF will automatically add items to the control, for example an `ItemsControl` when an object has been added to your list.

I found `ObservableCollection<T>` very useful, since it takes away a lot of work you had to do when using `INotifyCollectionChanged`, but that is just a suggestion.

Comment: If i take observable collection as the dependency property then the binded objects must be an observable collection. My problem is, I want to do somthing on User control when the collection is modified.

Comment: @user3608101: Then you have to rely on code. Just hook up the event handler in the xaml.cs file.

Comment: on what event. that is what my question.